# Magento product page Breadcrumbs SEO

Tags: magento, seo, breadcrumbs

I have a problem. I haven't found info how google should see breadcrumbs of the product page. Tried a few fixes, but these didn't worked correctly. For example if I go to product **www.domain.com/shoes-255**
and use that in this tool https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/ . I see 2 breadcrumbs, one is **HOME** and another one is **Product name**.

Breadcrumbs path on the page is: **HOME > MAN > SHOES > SPORT > Product name**.
This product have few parent categories.

So the question is: Should I see all breadcrumbs (**HOME , MAN , SHOES , SPORT , Product name**) from full path with all categories or everything is good as I see now (**HOME , Prodcut name**)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good as it is now (Home > Product name). I suppose this product is linked on the homepage and you clicked it and went to the product detail page?! Therefore the breadcrumb is *Home* (from where you're coming) and *Product name* (product detail page, where you are).

All fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in Magento admin under **System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization**  called `Use Categories Path for Product URLs`. Setting this to No means that the product page will all sit as though at the root of your site: i.e -

Setting to Yes: `test.com/football/clothing/shoes/adidas-predators.html`

Setting to No: `test.com/adidas-predators.html`

I could be wrong but I think the structured data is done that way by default to prevent duplicate content? For example, you may have the same product in multiple categories; so two pages will exist displaying the same content:

`test.com/football/clothing/shoes/adidas-predators.html` and `test.com/rugby/clothing/shoes/adidas-predators.html`